# Display List View from Subsite on Parent Site

Tags: 2013, list, workflow, sharepoint-calendar

I've got a list setup on a HR subsite that keeps tracks of Scheduled Vacations for employees. I'd like a way to display a certain view from this list as a web part on the Parent of this site. I figured just copying the list items to a list located on the parent site would be the easiest way, but the workflow that populates the subsite list can't 'see' anything located on the parent site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use content query webpart ,where you can display list from the sub-site an add the columns as per the requirement.

[image]

Comment: this is wired, How can this be what you needed?? you can't modify or tune your list design here ... it offers some default display options otherwise you can customise nothing (you cannot even specify JSLink)

Comment: Karoui - you can create a custom display template easily enough.

Comment: How to show all the columns or some certain columns?