# Show Sub-site's List in main site page

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sub-site

I have a list in one sub-site, now I want to add/show that list on a page in its  main site.

It should be with edit menu of the list content.

Any suggestion !

Comment: Entire list or just list view with columns?

Comment: A  particular list view with add/edit menu..

Comment: You can achieve it by below given solution...

Answer (score 2):

> You can use content query webpart ,where you can display list from the
>   sub-site an add the columns as per the requirement.
>
> [image]

This might help you..!

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a Content Query WebPart on the parent site page to display the items from your subsite.

Please have look to this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85022/display-list-view-from-subsite-on-parent-site)