# Listing Documents in root site's document library folder with the documents listed in a sub site's document library

Tags: document-library, sub-site

I have company documents library folder in my parent site. I would like it to list the documents from a department(sub site) within the company site(parent site).

Is there a step by step tutorial to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement I think you can use Content Query WebPart/Content Search WebPart for the same. Because Content Query WebPart has a property to display data from Sub site too.

Your question might be answered [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/85022/display-list-view-from-subsite-on-parent-site)

Let me know if this solves your problem or you need some more assists.